# Why is drop event being called for multiple objects?

Tags: javascript, html

When this code is used for a chrome extension in a content script, both draggable elements are created, and are individually resizable, however when drag and dropped they both end up in the same position.

Using log statements I determined that the drag_start event is only called for the element which is clicked on when dragged, but the drop event is always called for both elements. I'm reasonably new to js so would be happy with any sort of help/advice

```js
function drag_start(event) {
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(event.target, null);
    event.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", (parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("left"), 10) - event.clientX) + ',' + (parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("top"), 10) - event.clientY) + ',' + event.target.getAttribute('data-item'));
  }
  
function drag_over(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
  
function drop(elem, event) {
    var offset = event.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain").split(',');
    elem.style.left = (event.clientX + parseInt(offset[0], 10)) + 'px';
    elem.style.top = (event.clientY + parseInt(offset[1], 10)) + 'px';
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
}

class Note {
    
    constructor(x, y, sx, sy, doc){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.doc = doc;
        this.div = doc.createElement("div");
        this.note_text = doc.createElement("textarea");
        this.note_text.setAttribute("type", "text");
        this.note_text.style.display = "inline-block";
        this.note_text.style.webkitBoxSizing = "border-box";
        this.note_text.style.boxSizing = "border-box";
        this.note_text.style.width = "100%";
        this.note_text.style.height = "100%";
        this.note_text.style.resize = "none";
        this.div.appendChild(this.note_text);
        this.div.draggable = true;
        this.div.style.resize = "both";
        this.div.style.overflow = "auto";
        this.div.className = "dragme";
        this.div.style.zIndex = "99999";
        this.div.style.position = "absolute";
        this.div.style.overflowX = "hidden";
        this.div.style.overflowX = "hidden";
        this.div.style.overflowY = "hidden";
        this.div.style.left = "0";
        this.div.style.top = "0";
        this.div.style.width = "200px";
        this.div.style.background = "rgba(100, 255, 255,1)";
        this.div.style.border = "2px solid rgba (0,0,0,1)";
        this.div.style.borderRadius = "4px";
        this.div.style.padding = "8px";
        this.doc.body.append(this.div);
        

        this.div.addEventListener('dragstart', drag_start, false);
        doc.body.addEventListener('dragover', drag_over, false);
        doc.body.addEventListener('drop', (event) => drop(this.div, event), false);
    }

}

const note1 = new Note(0,0,0,0,document);
const note2 = new Note(0,0,0,0,document);
```

Comment: try with `event.preventDefault(); event.stopPropagation();`

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia unfortunately didn't make any difference

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by using a separate variable which the target element is assigned to on the "dragstart" event. This variable is then re-positioned on the on drop event, so will be unique to the element dragged rather than all draggable elements.